# Flask WTF Form Validation Error

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am new to Flask and am trying to take a user entered name from a login form and pass it to another page. With my current code, the form does not pass the `result` page any argument and returns `none` when `request.args.get('artistName')` is called in the `result` view. What is wrong? `print form.errors` does not show anything.

The `views.py` programme:

```
from flask import render_template, request, url_for, redirect

from app import app
from .forms import UserName

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = UserName()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/result')

    render_template('home.html',form=form)

@app.route('/result', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result(name):
    return render_template('results.html')
```

The `home.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <form action="{{ url_for('result') }}" method='post'>
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.hidden_tag }}
    <p>Enter your artist name: </p>
    {{ form.artistName(size=100) }}
    {{ form.submit }}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And `forms.py`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class UserName(FlaskForm):
    artistName = TextField('artistName', [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Go")
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: If you do a GET to `/` what does the generated form HTML look like?

Comment: I apologise, but could you be more explicit?

Comment: Nevermind... I think the issue might be due to your URL structure. If the user is specifying an artist name, the parameter should not be part of the route, but rather in the query string. For example: `/result?name=foo`.  If you change the method of your form to `GET` and remove the `name` parameter from your `url_for` statement that gets you pretty close.

Comment: `<form action="{{ url_for('result') }}" method='get'>` Did you mean like so? If so this results in `BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'result'. Did you forget to specify values ['name']?`

Comment: take the <name> parameter out of the view function and then use request.args.get('artistName') to access the field. the url won't build without the parameter the way it is configured.

Comment: Just noticed that `action="{{ url_for('result', name=userName) }}"` skips the form validation clause. But if I change it to `action=""`, and make `if form.validate_on_submit():` render `url_for('result')` the form is never validated and merely refreshes `('/')`. How can I maintain form validation?

Comment: Move the `form.validate_on_submit()` block into your `result` function. You should be able to access `form.artistName.data` from inside the moved block.

Comment: @dana I couldn't get that to work, I have updated the question so you can see what I was trying.

Comment: Have a look at your errors by adding `print form.errors` in your view function. This should give you an idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a return statement in your login view:

```
return render_template('home.html',form=form)
```